# Handlebars Template and bxSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, bxslider

I'm having some trouble with the bxSlider implementation in a handlebars template trying to create a vertical carrousel. I wait until the window is fully loaded to call the slider but the bxviewport seems not to calculate the height.

The problem is that when it moves one slide the viewport-height goes down to 0. I think that is due to adding the html content with a template. bxSlider is may be getting the height of the slide sooner than it is filled with the content provided by the template

```
<div class="tweetDeck"  >
                        <p style="text-align:center"><a href="#"><img width="30px" src="../images/twitter.png"></a>#topic</p>

                        <ul class="tweets">
                            <script id="tweets-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                                {{#each this}}
                                <li class="vSlide" height="150px">

                                    <p>{{tweet}}<br/>
                                    {{author}}
                                </li>
                                {{/each}}
                            </script>


                        </ul>
                </div>
                <script>
                //This is where I call the slider

                $(window).bind('load',function(){

                    $('ul.tweets').bxSlider({
                    auto:false,
                    minSlides:3,
                    maxSlides:3, 
                    moveSlides:1,
                    mode:'vertical',
                    pager:false,
                    controls:true,
                    slideSelector:'li.vSlide',



                    });
                    //This code bellow is useless, it's overrided after the first slide 
                    $('.tweets').parent('.bx-viewport').css({
                        'height':500
                    })

                })


                </script>
```

As I said the output result is the viewport's height with value 0 after the first move. I've tried it without the templating and it works fine.

Does anyone tried this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I finally solved with a timer, checking the length of li. Once the ul it's filled with the template  I call the slider function and bxSlider can do its size maths right.

```
 function checkFeedsTimer() {
                        var feeds = $('.tweets li').length;
                        console.log(feeds)
                        if (feeds > 0 ){
                            $('ul.tweets').bxSlider({
                                auto:false,
                                minSlides:3,
                                maxSlides:3, 
                                moveSlides:1,
                                mode:'vertical',
                                pager:false,
                                controls:true,
                                slideSelector:'li.vSlide',          
                            });

                        }else{
                            setTimeout(checkFeedsTimer, 500);
                        }

                    }

                    checkFeedsTimer();
```